# Is there any way to open appstore updates tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect, updates

Sometimes we are forcing users to update their apps from AppStore. We show an alert if new mandatory version is available and open app page from AppStore. Instead of showing update button, AppStore shows the open button. I know its a bug and there are a lot of threads about it. Instead of showing app page, can i show the updates tab? Is there any url for it?

Comment: you want to redirect to your app page in appstore

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i want to open updates tab in AppStore not my app page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible for sure. You can only open application page from application.